# How to Disassociate an Apple ID from a work computer

Tags: imac, apple-id

How do I disassociate an Apple-ID from an iMac? I am trying to push updates on a work computer but I can not. I am unable to because a previous employee's apple ID pops up and I do not have the password. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't without the Apple ID info of the original owner/user.

However, there is a workaround. If you reinstall the original OSX associated with the machine using **[Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)**, this will enable you to sign in using your Apple ID and subsequently upgrade the OS from there. Note that this will not work using the simple recovery mode (the partition already on the disk).

Although reinstallation is non-destructive, it's always a good idea to back up beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways a Mac might be linked to a particular Apple ID, and how you disassociate it depends on how ir's linked. Installing system updates shouldn't require any Apple ID. Are you updating apps that were purchased from the App Store? If so, those apps are permanently linked to the Apple ID that purchased/downloaded them, and the only way to remove the association is to delete the app(s) and re-purchase/re-download them under your Apple ID.

Comment: System updates require an Apple ID.

Comment: @njboot Apple distinguishes between system "updates" (minor updates like 10.13.0 -> 10.13.4, which *don't* require an Apple ID to download and install) from "upgrades" (major version upgrades like Sierra 10.12.x -> High Sierra 10.13.x, which *do* require an Apple ID to download, but it doesn't have to be the same as was used any previous upgrade/install). In either case, there's no worry about disassociating from an old ID.

Comment: I hate to press this and I'm aware of the difference, but you must be signed in to the App Store in order for updates to automatically download and install ((Preferences > App Store). Otherwise you will be prompted with a push notification asking you to sign in using your Apple ID in order to update to 10.13.x > 10.13.y. You cannot update the system without signing in.

Comment: @njboot Hmm, I'll have to test that with 10.13; it's not been my experience with any previous version of macOS.

Comment: @njboot I finally got a chance to test this, and was able to run install the OS, and install OS updates both via download+manual install method, and via the App Store's Updates tab, without ever entering an Apple ID.